# Lubuntu 18.04 LTS freezes on shutdown and reboot

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, shutdown, freeze, reboot

Yeah, I know there were similar topics here, but still, I need help. I am running Lubuntu 18.04 LTS on Intel Celeron J1800, 2GB RAM and iGPU, with 500GB HDD. Everytime I press shutdown, reboot, write them in terminal and that's not working... Alway's stuck on "Lubuntu .... " screen with those dots, which are freezing after some time. I have to hold power button to turn it of. Any way to solve it?

EDIT:
Here is my `inxi -Fxxxz`:

```
System:    Host: server-0001 Kernel: 4.15.0-34-generic x86_64
           bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: LXDE (Openbox 3.6.1) info: lxpanel dm: lightdm
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop System: ASUS product: All Series serial: N/A
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: J1800I-C v: Rev X.0x serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: 0604 date: 06/10/2014
CPU:       Dual core Intel Celeron J1800 (-MCP-) 
           arch: Silvermont rev.8 cache: 1024 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9662
           clock speeds: min/max: 1332/2582 MHz 1: 1333 MHz 2: 1332 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
           bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0f31
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1680x1050@59.95hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Bay Trail
           version: 4.2 Mesa 18.0.5 (compat-v: 3.0) Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Def. Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:0f04
           Card-2 Creative Sound Blaster Tactic(3D) Sigma sound card
           driver: USB Audio usb-ID: 001-005 chip-ID: 041e:3220
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-34-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: e000
           bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
           driver: ath9k bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 168c:002b
           IF: wlp4s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (6.0% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD5000AAKX size: 500.1GB
           serial: <filter> temp: 22C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 457G used: 29G (7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
RAID:      System: supported: N/A
           No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
           Unused Devices: none
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 32.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 139 Uptime: 1 min Memory: 262.5/3806.6MB
           Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.3.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191 running in lxterminal) inxi: 2.3.56terminal) inxi: 2.3.56`
```

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade`? It's possible that updating may solve your problem. If you get any error messages or warnings, post the entire output here. Also, if you install `inxi` and post the output of `inxi -Fxxxz`, people may have a better idea of your system.

Comment: Have you tried any of those many similar topics? Can you elaborate on how your problem is different from those similar topics? Otherwise, our answers will be exactly the same as those, or this may be closed as a duplicate of those.

Comment: @user535733 yeah, I tried every of them. I don't really know, because it seems similliar - there is only difference when I am getting this freeze.
@DKBose I did both `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: However I figured out, that it is turning off properly using `halt -p` and `shutdown -h now`... I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running similar hardware (ASUS J1800I-A SoC), and my solution was to completely disable **CSM** in EFI settings and switch "**Secure boot**" value from "**Windows**" to "**Other OS**".